# Can't print out the correct values from my linked list C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, linked-list

I am having trouble printing the correct values of my linked list after nodes have been inserted into it.
The struct for my linked list is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 50
struct car{
  int car_number;
  int speed;
  int consumption;
  int reliability;
};

struct teams{
  char team_name[SIZE];
  struct elem_fila *car_list_root;
};

struct elem_fila{
  struct car car_info;
  struct elem_fila *next_car;

};
```

The struct teams is a struct that will have a linked list of elem_fila structs which each have information about a car.

My insertion code is the following:

```
    void insert(struct car c, struct elem_fila **root){

  struct elem_fila *aux, *next, *previous;

  aux = (struct elem_fila *) malloc(sizeof(struct elem_fila));

  //Something went wrong
  if (aux == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  aux->car_info = c;
  aux->next_car = NULL;
  printf("%d\n", aux->car_info.speed);
  //If the root is null
  if (*root == NULL){
    *root = aux;
    printf("%d\n", (*root)->car_info.speed);


  }
  //If the root is not null
  else{
    printf("%d", aux->car_info.speed);
      previous = *root;
      next = (*root)->next_car;

          while (next != NULL) {
              previous = next;
              next = next->next_car;
          }
          previous->next_car = aux;
          aux->next_car =NULL;
      }
      printf("%d", (*root)->car_info.speed);
}
```

The insertion algorithm works as following: every new element gets put on the  back of the list.Here the "prints" work fine even when inserting a new element, the root element still prints the values put in before.

But when I call my print list algorithm everything goes wrong and it prints out random values (probably memory addresses). Here is the code:

```
void printList(struct elem_fila *root){
  struct elem_fila *current;
  printf("%d\n", (root)->car_info.speed);
  current = root;


  while(current != NULL ){
    printf("Numero carro: %d, Velocidade: %d, Consumption: %d, Reliability:%d\n",current->car_info.car_number,
                                                                                current->car_info.speed,
                                                                                current->car_info.consumption,
                                                                                current->car_info.reliability);
   current = current->next_car;

  }
  return;
}
```

Here the printf on the second line instead of giving the number 30 (the one I was inserting as a test) it was giving me the number 741355568. I am calling the functions as following :

```
void teste2(){
  strcpy(team_list[0].team_name,"Team A");
  struct car carro = { 10, 30, 50, 60};
  struct car carro2 = { 100, 80, 90, 70};
  insert(carro, &team_list[0].car_list_root);
  insert(carro2, &team_list[0].car_list_root);

  printf("%s" ,team_list[0].team_name);
  printList(team_list[0].car_list_root);
}
```

Note: team_list is an array of team structs.
Note2: the team's name is printing like intended

If anyone could help I would appreciate it a lot. I have been trying for a long time but can't seem to find the problem!

Comment: Cleaning up the indentation would be a good start.

Comment: How is `team_list` initialized?  Are you sure that `team_list[0].car_list_root == NULL` before beginning the insertions?

Comment: You seem to be missing a few includes, and your [cast of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) may be hiding some of the resulting problems.

Comment: With those things fixed, your program runs for me without errors and with correct output, even under valgrind/AddressSanitizer (it has memory leaks of course).

Answer (score 0):

I changed few things and it compiled and run successfully as it meant to be..

first, i added the libraries string.h and stdlib.h.

created a main who triggered test2.

in test2 i declared a array of struct team, and gave it 100 indices.

i compiled it and run it and **this is the output:**

```
30
30
3080
8030Team A30
Numero carro: 10, Velocidade: 30, Consumption: 50, Reliability:60
Numero carro: 100, Velocidade: 80, Consumption: 90, Reliability:70
```

i think this is what you want..

also, you need to free your dynamically allocation before you exit the program.

i used gcc to compiled it with this flags

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -g
```